# JUnit test can't create an Account

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit4, account

I'm trying to run some test in my app, but when I try to create an `Account(name, type)` the result is always `null` in JUnit but working properly when I run the app

**Example:**

```
class ExampleTest {

@Rule
@JvmField
val instantExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()
@Rule
@JvmField
val trampolineSchedulerRule = TrampolineSchedulerRule()

val ACCOUNT_NAME = "ACCOUNT_NAME"
val ACCOUNT_TYPE = "ACCOUNT_TYPE"

@Test
fun createAccountTest() {
    val account = Account(ACCOUNT_NAME, ACCOUNT_TYPE)

    assertThat(account.name, `is`(ACCOUNT_NAME))
}
}
```

Is there any special way to create an Account when I run test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are trying to perform this type of test in the `test` directory, which is the one for unit tests.

In this case you are accessing a framework class so you need to put the test in your `androidTest` directory where reside the instrumented tests.

In my environment this test is green:

```
import org.junit.Assert.assertEquals
import org.junit.Assert.assertNotEquals

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class AccountTest {

    @Test
    fun accountCreationTest() {
        val account = Account("NAME", "TYPE")
        assertEquals(account.name, "NAME")
        assertNotEquals(account.name, "WRONGNAME")
    }

}
```